# What causes the gap between the border and content on some of my list items?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items with some styling. Basically, I have an anchor inside the list item, and the anchor has the gray background etc, while the item itself has a gradient bottom border.

Between some items, I get a white line. I've found that it's caused by the list item it self 'shining through' the label. Why?

It looks like it doesn't happen if no anchor text wraps.
It also doesn't happen if the bottom border has an even thickness (2px, 4px, etc)

I *know* I can hide the effect by setting the background color on the item itself. I'm more interested in *why* it happens then how to solve it.

[image]

Here's a link to a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-bh7qnw?file=/styles.css) showing the effect.

Comment: Is your page zoom set to something other than 100%?

Comment: Nope, but windows scaling is set to 150%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are coming across a fairly well known problem.

It arises when the system is trying to map CSS pixels into the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on many modern screens.

Sometimes a screen pixel gets ‘left behind’ so causing a narrow line.

It’s a bit like a rounding error.

It can often be seen when zooming at certain levels. The fact that you see it on 1px sizing is what makes me feel this is the problem here too.

Comment: I have a highres monitor and windows scales to 150%. So that might be the reason?